# Script to refactor assignment a.x=3 to setter method a->setX(3)

Tags: javascript, c++, regex, node.js, shelljs

I'm converting part of my code from JS to C++ thus I need to refactor direct instance variables assignment into setter methods:

`a.xx=3;` to `a->setXx(3);`

and also getter methods:

`...a.xx...` to `...a->getXx()...`

Currently I use **shelljs (node.js)** for the conversions.
Sample command for renaming a function from oldMethod() to newMethod():

```
sed('-i', /\boldMethod[ ]*\(/g, 'newMethod(', filename);
```

Preferably I would use the same technique fro the setters/getter. However I'm open to use other acceptable approach too.

My problems:

1. I can not get the tagged substitutions working
2. I'll need to capitalize the first letter
3. I'm not sure how to set proper conditions for the getter methods. There is no clear expression like `X=Y;` I can't simply turn all `alphanum.alphanum` into getters because it would also replace incorrect expressions e.g. `a("foo.doo");`
   My suggestions:

   a. do it anyway and manually update the incorrect replacements

   b. supply a set of valid variable names, e.g. `"tag|possition|rotation|..."`

Comment: Hmm - I would have imagined that this the least of your problem in trying to convert between JS and C++!

Answer (score 3):

In C++ we are less precious about using "getters" and "setters" as really they do little more than circumvent whilst appearing to respect encapsulation.

There's nothing wrong with using `a->xx=3;`, having made the `xx` member `public`. That will simplify your conversions.

Comment: There is something wrong about `a->xx = 3;`: `a` is a pointer *gasp* :)

Comment: I understand that. But I'm using cocos2d framework which in JS uses n.tag=3 but in C++ requires to use setter because the member is protected :-(

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to enumerate all known methods. It's less flexible but it works.

```
var inf = process.argv[2];

sed('-i', /\b([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\.tag[ ]*=[ ]*(.+);/g, '$1->setTag($2);', inf);
sed('-i', /\b([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\.tag\b/g, '$1->getTag()', inf);

sed('-i', /\b([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\.z[ ]*=[ ]*(.+);/g, '$1->setZ($2);', inf);
sed('-i', /\b([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\.z\b/g, '$1->getZ()', inf);

sed('-i', /\b([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\.pos[ ]*=[ ]*(.+);/g, '$1->setPos($2);', inf);
sed('-i', /\b([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\.pos\b/g, '$1->getPos()', inf);
```